# How to do TDD implementing BLoC pattern on Flutter

Tags: flutter, tdd, bloc, flutter-test

I am a student in iOS mobile development, and I recently learned about code architectures (MVC) and tests (TDD), and I understand how it saves so much time during development specifically during refactoring.

So I tried on my side to find some resources about those topics for Flutter, but I found only resources about BloC or TDD with Clean architecture.

Is there a specific way to do TDD using the BLoC pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only tutorial that I've seen implementing TDD and Bloc is [this](https://resocoder.com/2019/08/27/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course-1-explanation-project-structure/) tutorial by Reso Coder, which might help you understand how you can use TDD with Bloc.

Comment: I have seen it, but he is using Clean architecture with BLoC, it confuses me. Have we to use another architecture with BLoC state management?

Comment: Well, no. There's no requirement to use an architecture while using Bloc, though it is recommended in larger projects. But as you know TDD is just a software development process, and if you know it, the only part which is left, I guess, is learning how to write tests. In any of these cases i think the course I mentioned can be helpful, cause a big part of this course is learning TDD and how to write tests, and I think what you learn is useful whether you use Clean architecture or only Bloc or any other approach.